# Question regarding wiring setup for a battery balancer

Tags: batteries

Given this schematics (it is a battery balancer for 6 x 12V lead-acid battery, wired so we have a 24V system).

[image]

Can someone please explain me why the inner black wires (the ones connecting + to -, so we link the batteries in series) are connected between them?

I understand the logic to measure/discharge a "channel" (right or left one) but I don't understand how linking the common wires (what I put in the green part) works.

Thanks!

Comment: Looking at it better now .. does it work like it is 2 separate batteries of 12V and them being linked together doesn't matter?

Comment: Well, if they weren't linked together you would need 6 balancers instead of 2. I have seen large battery packs assembled both with and without those cross-connections. I think it is more common to have cross connections. But the pack will work either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't link middle points together, you will have 3 different battery packs to balance separately and 3 separate balancing circuits. You will add both cost and complexity for no aparent gain.

On the other hand, if you connect the middle points together, there is a good chance of weaker and stronger batteies distributing between the sides of the circuit in a pattern that lowers the need of balancing.